# Why keras middle layer output tensor shape is (?,?)

Tags: python, model, keras

I loaded a keras model and used its middle output as follows:

```
pretrain_model = load_model(path)
model = Model(inputs=pretrain_model.input, outputs=pretrain_model.layers[-2].output)
```

When I run:

```
>>model.output
<tf.Tensor 'pretrain_variable/dropout_2/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>
>>model.output_shape
(None, 2000)
```

This influences my next step:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,X_all.shape[1],X_all.shape[2]),name='X')
pretrain_output = pretrain_model(input) # pretrain_output shape should be none*2000, however it is none*none
output_y = Dense(units=y.shape[1])(pretrain_output) # this works
output_y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=y.shape[1])(pretrain_output) # won't work, cause pretrain_output shape is (none,none)
```

I cannot use tf.keras.layers.Dense directly due to Dimension equals none.
Can anyone teach me how to get the middle layer output with correct shape?

Comment: What does the `pretrain_model` look like?

Comment: Its a text-cnn keras model. I ommited the detailed information due to the comment length limit.
Input->conv1d->batch_normalization->conv1d->batch_normalization->max_pooling1d->flaten->concatenate->dropout->dense(softmax)